# django-autocomplete-light django 1.8 custom modelform for admin

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I want add autocomplete for OneToOne field to django-admin

```
class Banner(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, null=True)

class BannerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BannerForm
```

stucked on https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/tutorial.html?highlight=tutorial#tutorial - **anything changed** after all following steps (same list widget for 'product' ...):

What I have done:

1. installed :D
2. added 'autocomplete_light', to INSTALLED_APPS
3. overrided admin/base_site.html (using custom loader)
4. url(r'^autocomplete/', include('autocomplete_light.urls')), to urlpatterns
5. autocomplete_light_registry.py with model **Banner** and **search_fields=['product'],**
6. updated modelform:

> ```
> class BannerForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Banner
>         fields = ['product', 'priority', 'image']
>         autocomplete_fields = ['product']
> ```

What I've missed?

Comment: Just guess might be the problem with this fields = ['product', 'priority', 'image'],try removing it and check.

Comment: @chandu nope ImproperlyConfigured"Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Following resolved my problem:

1. before admin in INSTALLED_APPS

> ```
>   INSTALLED_APPS = (
>     'autocomplete_light',
>     'django.contrib.admin',
>   )
> ```

2. autocomplete_light_registry.py

> ```
> class BannerAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
>     model = Banner
>     search_fields = ('name',)  # banner_obj.product.name
>     choices = Product.objects.all()
>     limit_choices = 20
>
>     autocomplete_light.register(
>         BannerAutocomplete,
>         attrs={
>             'placeholder': _(u'имя товара'),
>             'data-autocomplete-minimum-characters': 1,
>         },
>     )
> ```

3. Manually select autocomplete for related field in your form:

> ```
> class BannerForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Banner
>         fields = ['product', 'priority', 'image']
>         autocomplete_names = {'product': 'BannerAutocomplete'}
> ```